# Meteor: accessing user details on client

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-accounts

I'm trying to access (another) user's details on the client side in meteor. I have a server side method called 'userDetails' that I'm calling from a template helper called 'acc'.

Server method:

```
'userDetails': function(userId) {
      check(userId, String);
      return Meteor.users.findOne({_id: userId},
                                  {fields: {
                                    "services.facebook.first_name": 1,
                                    "profile.birthday": 1,
                                    "services.facebook.gender": 1,
                                    "profile.location.name": 1
                                  }});
    }
```

Template helper:

```
acc: function(_id) {
    Meteor.call('userDetails', _id, function(err, res) {
      if(err) throw error;
      return res;
    });
  }
```

When I try to access acc.profile.birthday in the template I don't get anything. What could cause this?

Comment: You cannot access a Template helper like that. You have to use `acc` in the Template itself to see the output.

Comment: Hi @BlazeSahlzen, are you saying I can't use {{acc.profile.birthday}} in the template? Because that's what I'm doing...

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I misunderstood. Yes, you can do that. You could try consoling `res` object before returning it just to be sure of what structure the object has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meteor calls are asynchronous calls, that is why your helper is not returning any data.

Best option here is to either use `Session` or `ReactiveVar` or `ReactiveDict`

I'll use `Session` option here

```
acc: function(_id) {
  Meteor.call('userDetails', _id, function(err, res) {
    if(err){

    }else{
      Session.set('userDetails', res)
    }

  });
  return Session.get('userDetails')
}
```

In your html you can use this helper like this

```
{{#if acc}}
  {{name}}
  ...
{{else}}
  <p>Information not found</p>
{{/if}}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `return` statement be outside the Method call?

Comment: Thanks, I managed to make it work with this approach.

Answer (score 2):

You have to wrap the return in a else statement.

```
if(error) {

}
else {
   return res;
}
```

The call to you method in asynchronous. This means that the callback function will be executed when your server method completes.

If you want to display the result on a template, you have two possibilities:

**1/ Use a session.**

```
acc: function(_id) {
  Meteor.call('userDetails', _id, function(err, res) {
    if(err){
    }else{
      Session.set('data', res)
    }

  });
  return Session.get('data')
}
```

**2/ Use Template subscriptions (better solution):**
On the server, you publish the data:

```
Meteor.publish("data", function(){
     return Meteor.users.findOne(...)
});
```

On the client, you subscribe:

```
Template.mytemplate.onCreated(function () {   
    Template.instance().subscribe("data");
});
```

Then directly on the client you will be able to create a helper and call the findOne.

In the html:

```
  {{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
    {{#each myHelper}}
       {{acc.profile.birthday}}
    {{/each}}
  {{else}}
    <p>Loading...</p>
  {{/if}}
```

Important Notice about users:
Users profile are editable by default. Please read this: https://dweldon.silvrback.com/common-mistakes

Comment: Thanks @hlx, it's a nice and comprehensive answer, however I'm not sure that I would have a second helper to return the session.

Comment: @L4zl0w I updated the answer so you won't need a second helper. Please mark the answer so the question does not appear a unanswered anymore